# Soldering ACN/ACL (blue/brown) wires to outlet plug?

Tags: ac, dc

I have a 12v 5.0a AC to DC power converter. I want to solder the ACN(blue) and ACL(brown) wires to an outlet plug I cut that has copper wire (black and white).

[image]

I hope I am on the right path here. If I am how do I know which ends to solder together?

I see in this diagram that Black/Brown is live, and White/Blue is netural. So does that mean I can wire Brown to Black and Blue to White?

[image]

Comment: If its a polarized connector your should check continuity especially with a connector from wherever that you just cut. Neutral is usually white in us but it varies in other parts of the world. You should really buy a pigtail with an earth ground

Comment: Your diagram shows that your PSUs require an earth (ground). Don't leave this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally wall connectors are not polarized: you can plug them either way. So which wire you solder to which shouldn't be too important.

Your LED PSU will most likely have a bridge rectifier built in, so it can work with live voltage on any wire. If you are unsure, look at the datasheet.

Comment: bridge rectifier has nothing to do with AC polarity.

Comment: @Jasen why not? It is a simplification, but the rectifier does exactly what the OP wants to know: rectifying AC, regardless of polarity.

Comment: live / neutral is a safety issue not a polarity issue, rectifying AC, is immaterial.

Comment: @Jasen: Oh, I may used the wrong words, now I think Iunderstand what you mean. But the cable the OP showed in the picture there is no PE wire.

Comment: yeah, but the bridge rectifier isn't what makes it work, most AC appliances will work fine with either line polarity, some will even be safe either way.

Answer (score 3):

It will work either way because they are not polarized (as jvsc said) but there is a difference and a correct way to connect them. One is hot and the other is neutral. The neutral wire (marked ACN) should go to the wider blade/prong and the hot wire (marked ACL) should go to the narrower blade.